# Get "NULL" records from the database without using "IS NULL" condition..?

Tags: mysql

How do i get all the NULL valued records from the table without using below conditions

```
"WHERE field_name IS NULL OR field_name = 'NULL' "
```

Is there any MySQL inbuilt function to resolve this..?

actually this is what question i have faced in one of the INTERVIEW for MYSQL. i'm very much eager to know the solution for that.

I really appreciate with your answer.Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking unless you're looking for the `ifnull()` statement. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: i think you cannot check NULL value as field_name = 'NULL', it will check for string with value NULL,  not for NULL value.

Comment: @GP Singh: yes..i m looking for find string "NULL" values not for blank values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
select COALESCE(colname,0) from table where
colname != coalesc(colname,0);
```

Comment: ok thank you sonal for fast response. i'll check it out and get back to you soon.

Comment: this seems a bit incorrect, you should compare `colname != coalesc(colname,0)`

Comment: yes bcz i dont try this now.. so i write may condition change

Answer (score 0):

you need a `Join` and the null-safe equal `<=>`

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   table a 
       JOIN (SELECT NULL AS v) b 
         ON a.field_name <=> b.v
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
SELECT *
FROM test_null
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM test_null
    WHERE !colval
)
```